# C# protobuf Deserialize Error with ZMQ, invalid write-type

Tags: c#, deserialization, zeromq, protobuf-net

I have two program. with server create 
    DiscoverServerMessage 
and serialize it by protobuf and send it by ZMQ. In Client side deserialize message but error:

```
Ivalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length.
```

I have below class in dll project.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class DiscoverServerMessage 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Port { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string IP { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public DiscoverServerMessage() { }
}
```

In Server Project have this code:

```
public class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ZContext ctx = new ZContext();
        ZSocket broadcastSrocket = new ZSocket(ctx, ZSocketType.PUB);
        broadcastSrocket.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:2666");
        ZFrame zfr;
        DiscoverServerMessage message = new DiscoverServerMessage() { Port = 2667 , ServerName = "My" };
        message.IP = "127.0.0.1";
        using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(str,message,PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
            zfr = new ZFrame(str.ToArray());
        }
        broadcastSrocket.Send(zfr);
    }
}
```

In client program :

```
public class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ZContext ctx = new ZContext();
        ZSocket subSocket = new ZSocket(ctx, ZSocketType.SUB);
        subSocket.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:2666");
        subSocket.SubscribeAll();
        ZError err;
        ZFrame zfr = subSocket.ReceiveFrame(out err);
        DiscoverServerMessage message;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(zfr.Read()))
        {
            message = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<DiscoverServerMessage >(stream,PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
        }
    }
}
```

what is my mistake?

Comment: note - in the client code, did you mean `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<DiscoverServerMessage>` ? (you put `<T>`, but that isn't a generic bit of code)

Comment: Tank you. I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to *forget* about the serialization part, and simply check whether what you send was what you received, so - get a copy of whatever `str.ToArray()` is (server) and compare it to whatever `zfr.Read()` is (client). If the two payloads aren't identical: *all other bets are off*. The easiest way to do that is usually via hex, so:

(server):

```
byte[] blob = str.ToArray();
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(blob); // <== get a copy of this somehow
zfr = new ZFrame(blob);
...
```

(client)

```
byte[] blob = zfr.Read();
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(blob); // <== get a copy of this somehow
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(blob))
...
```

and just check: are the two hex sequences identical?

Note: since you're using a framing protocol (`ZFrame`), you *don't actually need the length prefix here*, but... it shouldn't hurt. It *looks* like you're using appropriate code at each end here - and the following (influenced by your code) works fine:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] blob;

        // taken from server code
        using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DiscoverServerMessage message = new DiscoverServerMessage() { Port = 2667, ServerName = "My" };
            message.IP = "127.0.0.1";

            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(str, message, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
            blob = str.ToArray();
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(blob));

        // taken from client code
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(blob))
        {
            DiscoverServerMessage message;
            message = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<DiscoverServerMessage>(stream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
            Console.WriteLine(message.Port);
            Console.WriteLine(message.ServerName);
            Console.WriteLine(message.IP);
        }

    }
}
```

The output here is:

```
12-00-00-00-08-EB-14-12-09-31-32-37-2E-30-2E-30-2E-31-1A-02-4D-79
2667
My
127.0.0.1
```

If we do the same thing just using `Serialize`/`Deserialize` (no length-prefix), we get (predictably):

```
08-EB-14-12-09-31-32-37-2E-30-2E-30-2E-31-1A-02-4D-79
2667
My
127.0.0.1
```

So it *should* work either with or without the length-prefix, as long as the client and server agree (which they appear to in your code).

Comment: I check two hex sequence. their are same.

Comment: @sharafi and are they the series I showed above? (for the same data, I mean)